# Grails JMS Plugin - need connection to startup?

Tags: grails, jms, activemq-classic

My grails app will not start up if the activeMQ service is not active at the location the app is trying to listen to.  When I start activeMQ then the grails up will start up fine.  I'd like to not have the dependency on activeMQ running in order to simply start the app.  Here's the WARN message that repeats while trying to run the grails app.

WARN org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Failed to connect to [tcp://localhost:61616] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.

Are there any configurations with the grails jms plugin or the activeMQConnection to allow the app to run without the initial dependency on activeMQ connection?  Thanks.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: ActiveMQ Version 5.8